# Is it possible to add multiple source files in dokker.json?

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js, jsdoc

I am trying to document my code using [dokkerjs](http://dokkerjs.com/) in my project which has multiple JavaScript files. Is it possible to summit a directory as source file for documentation in `.dokker.json`?

I refered [this](https://github.com/oceanhouse21/dokker/blob/master/.dokker.json) link.

```
  {
  "dir": "docs",
  "literate": {
    "source": "dokker.js",
    "dir": "annotated"
  },
  "jsdoc": {
    "title": "Dokker.js",
    "source": "dokker.js", // want to add multiple files here , I tried *.js
    "markdown": "README.md",
    "html": "index.html",
    "readme": "README.md",
    "template": "templates/index.ejs.html",
    "github": "https://github.com/oceanhouse21/dokker/blob/master/dokker.js",
    "site": "http://dokkerjs.com"
  },
  "mocha": {
    "command": "mocha --reporter doc",
    "test": "test/dokker.js",
    "path": "tests.html",
    "template": "templates/tests.ejs.html"
  }
}
```